# How does Live Wallpaper Works in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, live-wallpaper

I want to develop some live wallpaper apps for my Android Device and wanted to know the theory behind "How live wallpaper works?", which file format its supports? and How I can make my own live wallpaper app?

I am currently a android developer with 3years of experience. but this is first time I will be work on Live Wallpaper concept..

Please Help Me. I didn't found much information on the internet..

Comment: Livewallpaper works as a service. You need to draw on surface view for showing wallpaper and handle touch.

Comment: This is good sample you can use it [Sample In GitHub](https://github.com/RandomFeatures/Live-Wallpaper-Android)

Comment: if you have any idea please share through any blog post please